# Expand and Animate Div Vertically and Horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, expand

I'm trying to make it so that the divs within my carousel slider will toggle and expand into a larger div that will fit within the carousel on-click and reset with new div contents. All the expanding divs I've looked at have only slid down, and the old div information remains.

This is the only JavaScript I've found, but I do not know how to apply it with new div information upon expanding.

```
$("#expand").click(function(){
    $(".article-container").animate({
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        top: "-50px",
        left: "-50px",
        opacity: 0.6,
    }, 1500 );
});
```

Here is the CSS for the container before expanding and after.

```
.article-container{
    float: left;
    width: 193px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 0 13px 0 0;
}

.article-container-expand{
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 13px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Hiya, take a look here - this should help: http://jsfiddle.net/theguywholikeslinux/87f4Y/ (sample how everything fits together) cheers,

Comment: This is great! I added the jquery script, and all CSS, HTML, and JavaScript as is, but I still can't get the animation to happen in my own file. Is there some other script I'm forgetting to add? Thanks.

Comment: Hiya, no worries :) Glad it helped, okies, hmmm can you re-create your issue in jsfiddle? or I hope you have query library included in your page, try an query alert('foo'); or something and see if alert happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply data changes after the animation then you need to specify a completion callback for the animate call:

```
$("#expand").click(function(){
  $(".article-container").animate({
      width: "100px",
      height: "100px",
      top: "-50px",
      left: "-50px",
      opacity: 0.6,
    }, 
    { duration: 1500,
      complete: function() {
        // update the content here
        // this is the item being animated
      }
    }
  );
});
```

See the [jQuery animate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)